# Is this a devious way to pass by reference in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I read this [blog post](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/passing-javascript-function-arguments-by-reference.html#fbid=xMMUo04wW3i) on how to potentially pass a primitive by reference to a function in JavaScript. At first glance it seems like it could work but I'm wondering what potential pitfalls could come of it.

```
function modifyVar(obj, val) {
    obj.valueOf = obj.toSource = obj.toString = function(){ return val; };
}

var myString = 'old string';
console.log(myString); // logs "old string"

myString = Object(myString); // convert to object
modifyVar(myString, 'new string');
myString = myString.valueOf(); // Was not in blog post. Added to return to primitive
console.log(myString); // logs "new string"
```

Comment: You cannot introduce pass-by-reference semantics into JavaScript (without altering the language spec).

Comment: It doesn't actually seem like your passing a variable by reference. Rather your just forcing it to *act* like it's a reference to another object.

Comment: Maybe you should first explain *why* you'd want to do something like this in the first place? Trying to make a language behave in a way it's not made to behave is typically a sign for impending disaster.

Comment: Also that blog post is just wrong.

Comment: Object.defineProperty can do it better, or you can say myString=['old string'], and always use [0] to use myString, but just "myString" to pass it around, or if you can coerce it you can just use it: alert(myString) since one-col arrays look like strings...

Comment: That's sort of what I expected to hear. My question is poorly worded. I'm looking to see if this is a dangerous way to emulate pass-by-reference that is available in other languages.

Comment: @Pointy now I'm disappointed that my linking to his article might have helped his SEO.

Comment: @CleverGirl ha ha ... well it's not like the code he posted won't work, it's just that it doesn't really do what he says. It's not really a big deal anyway; lack of pass-by-reference is not really a problem in any practical sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not.  You are just going to a lot of effort to simulate modification of an unmodifiable object (even if Javascript were pass-by-reference, Strings are immutable).

Comment: Good point about strings. Since we can't actually pass by reference the above is just trying to emulate it and using a string was how this approach was shown in the blog post.

Answer (score 2):

A much cleaner way would be to pass an object and modify its properties. E.g.

```
function modifyVar(obj, val) {
    obj.myString = val
}

var obj = {myString: "Old string"};

console.log(obj.myString); // Old String
modifyVar(obj, "New String");
console.log(obj.myString); // New String
```